# Where is the "MAME" or "Visual Pinball" but for slot machines?

Tags: game, simulation, emulator

MAME is a free **arcade** video game emulator. It lets you play classic arcade games without having the actual arcade machine. The classic/primitive ones are quite well emulated by now.

Visual Pinball is a free **pinball** machine emulator. It lets you play classic pinball machines without having the actual thing. It actually looks amazingly photo-realistic.

But where is the similar free program to emulate classic, real-life **slot machines**? That is, "one-armed bandits".

I have just as much nostalgia for those wonderful electromechanical slot machines as I have for arcade games and pinball machines, but there seems to be no such thing. I want to see a virtual 3D room, darkened, with those inviting, blinking lights, and hear the coins dropped into the coin input mechanism, pulling the lever (or pressing the button, depending on the model), watching the fruit wheels spin and see the various lights light up, the chrome parts reflecting the environment, etc.

Naturally, any money you win would be purely virtual. I'm not talking about some crappy "app" or website with a digital slot machines -- there are countless of those and they hold zero interest with me, just as modern physical slot machines in general, which are nothing but computers with screens.

The ones I want to see are the classic models that were around in the 1980s and 1990s. Also, similar machines such as "poker machines" would also be of interest.

Again, it's important that they simulate actual machines that have existed. Not "fantasy" ones!